# asp.net mvc html.ActionLink object routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Download", "MyFile", "Jobs", new { MetaValue = MetaValues}, null)%>
```

how can i avoid the object routes to display in the url?

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to hide URLs. If you need security, there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't avoid route values being displayed in the url. They are part of the url. This is their nature. Depending on your scenario and on what you are trying to do there are other ways to avoid sending sensitive information in the url.

If it is just a matter of not displaying them in the url you could use an HTML form with a POST request and a hidden field containing the value. This way it won't be part of the url but the user can still see it and tamper with it (a little more difficult because he needs to use some tools but still feasible).